# Fetch specific records from a csv file, based on user defined conditions

Tags: python, csv

I have been trying to write a program, which will help the user see the details of a student by entering only an attendance id.

```
import csv
field = ["Roll no" , "Name" , "Class","Section"]
f = open("student.csv" , 'w')
d=csv.writer(f)
d.writerow(field)
ch='y'
while ch=='y' or ch=='Y':
    gr=int(input("Enter GR number: "))
    nm = input("Enter name:")
    cls = input("Enter Class:")
    sec = input("Enter section:")
    rec=[gr,nm,cls,sec]
    d.writerow(rec)
    ch=input("Enter more record??(Y/N)")

f.close()

f=open("student.csv" , "r")
d=csv.reader(f)
next(f)
s=int(input("GR no of student whose details have to be displayed"))
print()
for i in d:
    if i[0]==s:
        print("grno=",i[0])
        print("Name=", i[1])
        print("class=", i[2])
        print("section =",i[3])
        print("--------------------")
f.close()
```

the error that i am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python310/myfile8.py", line 25, in <module>
    if i[0]==s:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Probably there is an empty line in "student.csv".

Comment: how do i fix that?

Comment: First of all check if there is really an empty or otherwise malformed line in the CSV.

Comment: any way to figure that out?

Comment: Use a text editor to look at the CSV.

Comment: Unclear why you need a CSV file at all. Store the data in a list, then search the list. You can (optionally) write the data to the CSV **after** printing all the data.... Also `i[0]` will be a string, which will never match the int input (you need to cast it)